# How to use Composer in PHP Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, composer-php

Can anyone explain how I can get Composer working in Google App Engine (PHP)? I understand what composer is and how it works but I have no idea on how to get it onto my App Engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run composer locally, and then upload the entire application that has been build by composer to production using the appcfg command.

Comment: Thank you! I finally understand how composer works now. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Really? I thought composer is not supported in GAE(?). http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9670 Can you clarify that it works?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam GAE doesn't support Composer. The answer is to install dependencies *locally* using Composer and then upload the entire application (including vendor dir) to GAE. In this case, Composer is no longer needed on Google's side. It is however a waste of bandwidth and time, uploading dependencies on each deployment.

Comment: Only changed files are uploaded when deploying, so after the first upload the there is no additional bandwidth or time consumed.

Comment: @Mike Yes. I know that. But it is still not enough. Google disables curl (unless enable billing) and other important extensions (which might be composer dependency) on GAE. So basically I, manually, need to search through and enable each missing extension. That is one large annoying task.

Comment: Why not just enable billing? GAE works with curl just fine and you can just set a max limit of $5 or something. I seriously doubt if you're on the free tier you'd even rack up more than 50 cents @KhurshidAlam